# Which OS can work as a fiber-channel target?

Tags: storage-area-network, fibre-channel

Just for the research, which OS can work from the box or with some 3rd-party software as a fc-target?

I know only the following: Solaris (currently only OpenSolaris+COMSTAR), Windows Storage Server.

Is that the only two above can?

Answer (score 4):

Linux can do this also. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/48168/is-it-possible-to-use-linux-as-a-fibre-channel-raid-disk-box), which points you to [SCST](http://scst.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD has support for using QLogic cards as FC Targets. See the [ISP](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isp) and [Targ](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=targ) drivers. Other cards may works as well, though I don't know of any off hand.

NetBSD supported these drivers as well, though I do not know if they still do.

Answer (score 0):

[Openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/products/openfiler-architecture)  support both target & initiator for FC (not FCoE).